# Convert nested 'for' loop to single 'for' loop in java

Tags: java, loops, nested

```
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    l=sc.nextLong();
    r=sc.nextLong();
    v=sc.nextLong();

    for(j=l-1;j<r;j++)
    {
        m=(int)j;
        ar[m]=ar[m]+(long)v;
    }
}
```

I'm solving a competitive programming question and I need to optimise this nested for loop to a single for loop. Code should have execution time below 2secs, this one takes 2 secs. Here k,l,r,v can be int values in the range 0 to 10^9.

Comment: The fact there are two loops here aren't what are causing the timeout. Much more likely that you're blocking for input.

Comment: without changing what your code does? not

Comment: The timing problem is not the nesting of loops but in `sc.nextLong`

Comment: Show your effort please?

Comment: ... execution time below 2s? For what input and what values of `k` and `r`? Unclear what you're asking, (imaginary) VTC.

Comment: @Stultuske ... yes, by using a lot of state variables.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't much magic we can do to turn a nested loop into 1 loop.

Comment: @byxor ... it's possible, why not?

Comment: Remember, less code doesn't mean faster to execute. (otherwise why are people using SO and not PPCG?)

Comment: @user202729 Are you _really_ encouraging that? Without a change of algorithm, there's no point in doing that.

Comment: Please show the variable types of all variables and their initial value.

Comment: @byxor (of course I'm not encouraging obfuscating the code for nothing, but it's certainly possible)

Comment: @user202729 It's probably possible, yes, but at that point you might as well become a compiler rather than a programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid two loops, but you can make it *sequential*, instead of nested.

```
long[] delta = new long[ar];
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    l=sc.nextLong();
    r=sc.nextLong();
    v=sc.nextLong();

    if (l-1 < r) {
        m=(int)(l-1);
        delta[m] = v;

        m=(int)r;
        if (m < delta.length) {
          delta[m] = -v;
        }
    }
}

long cumulative = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < ar.length; ++a) {
  cumulative += delta[a];
  ar[a] += cumulative;
}
```

Rather than keeping on incrementing the values in `delta` for each of the `l,r` ranges, this just stores a "delta" array: this stores a `+v` at the index where you'd start incrementing the array by `v`; and `-v` at the index where you'd stop.  So, recording that the range between `l` and `r` should be incremented by `v` is now an O(1) operation, rather than an O(r-l) operation.

So, some portion of this array looks like:

```
     2    
 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0
                -2
```

(I'm just vertically shifting the 2s to make it clearer)

If you calculate the cumulative sum of these elements:

```
     2 2 2 2 2 2  
 0 0             0 0 0 0
```

In other words, you can show a range where you are going to increment by 2 by storing just the start and end positions of this range.

This is what the `cumulative` variable stores: it's just the sum of all the elements in the `delta` array to the left of and including the current position. And that's the amount to increment the corresponding element of `ar` by.